# Dúvida sobre Consulta MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, xampp

Qual o código necessário para exibir todas as postagens de um usuário?
Fiz algo assim no PHP:

```
"SELECT * FROM postagens WHERE id='$p_id' AND u_id='$u_id';";
```

Mas sempre retorna 0 linhas :(

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS social
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
USE social;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuarios(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
    sobrenome VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    senha VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    sexo enum('M','F'),
    perfil VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL,
    capa VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL,
    recado VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT u_id_pk PRIMARY KEY(id)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS postagens(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    u_id INT,
    titulo VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    conteudo VARCHAR(4096),
    imagem VARCHAR(256),
    video VARCHAR(256),
    audio VARCHAR(256),
    CONSTRAINT id_pk PRIMARY KEY(id),
    CONSTRAINT u_id_fk FOREIGN KEY(u_id) REFERENCES postagens(id)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: já checou se os ids que estão chegando (p_id e u_id) existem no banco?

Comment: E usando `id='$p_id'` só retornará um registro.

Comment: as ids existem e sobre retornar apenas 1 é proposital pois estou com uma função no php para pegar um por vez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entenda o que o seu SQL está fazendo:

```
SELECT * FROM postagens WHERE id = '$p_id' AND u_id = '$u_id';
```

Seleciona todas as colunas da tabela postagens se o id da postagem for igual a `$p_id` e o id do usuário for igual a `$u_id`, ou seja vai retornar um registro em que os id for iguais aos atribuidos

Imagino que tu queira algo assim:

```
SELECT * FROM postagens WHERE u_id = '$u_id';
```

A mesma coisa porém sem a condição `id = '$p_id'`, isso retorna todos os registros da tabela postagens de um determinado usuário

**CUIDADO:** Esse seu código está sujeito a ataques [SQL Injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/)